# Kinds of finite dimensional inner product spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is very simple, I'm studying inner product spaces and every Algebra Linear book I read speaks only about vector spaces over $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R$, why? are there finite dimensional inner product spaces other than $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R$? Btw every vector spaces can be an inner product space?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ever finite-dimensional *vector space* over $\mathbb{R}$ (respectively $\mathbb{C}$) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (respectively $\mathbb{C}^n$) for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Furthermore, every inner products in a finite-dimensional space vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ (respectively $\mathbb{C}$) can be represented by matrix $M$ such that $$
  x\cdot y = x^TM y \text{ or } x\cdot y = x^T M \bar y \text{.}
$$

You can, of course, also have vector spaced over finite fields $K$, but since those fields have the property that $\underbrace{x + \ldots + x}_{\text{$n$ times}} = 0$, some things might not work out as they do over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: If the field $F$ has characteristic $0$, is there any trouble to work with this general finite dimensional vector space $F$?

Comment: @user42912 The vector space over a finite field $K$ is mostly unaffected, as far as I remember. But inner products will behave strangely I guess - for example, if $K$ has characteristic $N$, and you compute the canonical inner product $x\cdot x = x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2$ for an $x \in K^N$, the product will be zero for $x = (1,\ldots,1)$.